# Can I make curl or wget restart if disconnected?

Tags: bash, shell-script, wget, curl, download

I'd like to download a file through `curl` - the problem is that my connection is very slow, and by unknown means, stops receiving data after ~180 kilobytes.

Unless there's a better method to fix it, I'd like to write a shell script that makes it run after disconnection, if the file is not entirely downloaded.

How such script would/should look like? Is it possible to achieve with shell script at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell `curl` to retry with the [`--retry` option](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--retry):

```
curl --retry 10 ...
```

will retry up to ten times to download the given URL.

It's worth checking the various related `--retry-...` options in the documentation; given that you're expecting errors, the default backoff algorithm may not be ideal, so `--retry-delay` will come in handy. As mentioned by [Sato Katsura](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117516/sato-katsura), the timeout options can also be useful (`--...-timeout` and `--max-time`).

If that fails, because `curl` encounters an error it doesn't consider to be transient, you can use a loop:

```
result=56
while [[ ${result} == 56 ]]; do
    curl -C - ...
    result=$?
done
```

You might want to add a counter in there to limit the number of loops.

Comment: Also relevant: the `--*-timeout` and `--max-time` options.

Comment: ... Although TBH the OP's problem sounds more like a broken firewall blocking ICMPs.  A possible solution assuming Linux: `sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling=0`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura if that adds anything, I can download files sent in Telegram smoothly. This issue, though appears both in bash and in browsers like Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt That kind of problem isn't necessarily right at your router, it can be anywhere along the way from your machine to the server.  A `tcpdump` capture might reveal it.

Comment: Also, @StephenKitt I applied retry, but still, curl exits with code 56. I'd like to find a method that runs it again with the `-C -` option.

Comment: @StephenKitt don't worry, I've seen it and it worked, thanks for it! The reason I didn't accept the answer yet is to keep up the possibility of other ones and to keep the question visible if anyone finds it useful.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt I wasn't worrying, I just wasn't sure you'd seen the update.